# What does "The set of continuous real-valued functions on the interval [0,1]" mean? How can a function be on an interval?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm starting a linear algebra class soon, and reading through the textbook, I found an example that wanted us to prove "The set of continuous real-valued functions on the interval [0,1] is a subspace of ℝ<sup>[0,1]</sup>". This question has been answered elsewhere, but I've never encountered such terminology before, so even reading that answer gets me confused.

In addition to the questions above, could someone answer, what is ℝ<sup>[0,1]</sup>? I've seen ℝ<sup>n</sup> where n is an integer. By my understanding, it denotes a set with n elements within real numbers. So how does the interval as n work in this notation? Does it reference two lists, one with length 0 and the other with length 1?

Comment: Correct it to read "real-valued functions defined on the interval $[0,1]$"

Answer (score 2):

Quite generally $A^B$ can refer to functions from $B$ to $A$.  For each element in $B$ you choose one of the elements of $A$ to be the value at that point.  In that sense $\Bbb R^{[0,1]}$ is the set of functions from $[0,1]$ to the reals.  For each point in the interval, it assigns a value of the function.

Comment: Note to the OP that this also makes sense for $\mathbb{R}^n$ **if** in this context we treat "$n$" as an abbreviation for "$\{1,2,...,n\}$" - a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is really a function which takes in a number $i$ from $1$ to $n$ and spits out the $i$th coordinate.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the clarification. If I am to understand it correctly, ℝ^n defaults to {1,2,...,n}. However, here we instead define it to start at 0, hence {0,1}. In other words, ℝ^[0,2] would be {0,1,2}? Or am I still wrong? Forgive me for using "^", not sure how to superscript in comments.

Comment: @Jwee No, $[0,1]$ refers to all the real numbers between $0$ and $1$ inclusive - there's a difference between square brackets (for closed intervals) and curly brackets (for sets). $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is a very "big" set - there's a natural way to view it as a vector space, but then it's infinite-dimensional (indeed its dimension is uncountable). Re: notation in comments, use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): e.g. to get "$\mathbb{R}^{\{1,2,3\}}$" you write "\$\mathbb{R}^{\{1,2,3\}}\$."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Got it. Thank you for clearing up my misunderstanding. And thank you for helping me learn more about syntax in Stack!

Answer (score 1):

The notation $A^B$ refers to the set of functions with domain $B$ and range $A$.

The notation $\mathbb R^n$ is a little different, but you can match it up with the previous notation by writing it in an alternative fashion as $\mathbb R^{\{1,...,n\}}$. In other words, an element of $\mathbb R^n$ is a function $x : \{1,...,n\} \to \mathbb R$, which is usually written in sequential form $(x_1,....,x_n)$ where $x_i$ and $x(i)$ mean the same thing.

The phrase "a function on the interval $[0,1]$" means "a function whose domain is the interval $[0,1]$".